# How to show proof of employment when applying for a UK visa?

Tags: visas, uk, visa-refusals, proof-provenance-of-funds, proof-of-employment

I recently got a visa refusal for UK visit visa. I provided a letter of employment from my hospital plus a letter of leave. It stated my job, position, salary. Visa officer stated that he is not satisfied with the above evidence and it has not been 3 months since I started my job. I couldn't submit my salary bank statement because they pay me in cash. What should I do to prove my employment?

Comment: You do not receive any paperwork from your employer when you are paid (salary slip)?

Comment: Cash is by default not a proof. You need a receipt of some sort.

Comment: Usually when you get paid in cash you sign some sort of ledger if this job is official.  With that you should be able to request a proof of salary.

Answer (score 4):

As an answer to your question, you can select any of these...

1. Work for an employer who uses [generally accepted accounting
   principles](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/g/gaap.asp) to pay their employees; or
2. Incorporate and send your employer invoices for the services you are
   providing; or
3. Wait until one of the above is true before applying again

UK decision-makers do not like cash-in-hand arrangements and their rationale is that if you do that in your own country then you will do it in the UK and thus breach the terms and conditions of your stay.  They also believe that an employee who has a cash-in-hand arrangement is not employed in a way that is considered permanent or stable.  It is also conceivable that you never worked there at all and obtained your confirmation letter fraudulently; while it may be unpleasant to think about these sorts of things, there is very little to prevent them from making that conclusion and they are paid to think of those possibilities.  Understanding how they think is invaluable...

It is their long-standing policy that the onus of proof is on the applicant.

So based upon what you wrote you have been working for three months at a cash-in-hand job and presented a bespoke confirmation letter (from your previous posts), and the ECO did not accept the evidence.  By all accounts, he made a good call and will likely make the same call in your future applications until your circumstances radically change.

If you continue to apply over and over again without acceptable proof they will refuse again and again and start to conclude that you are desperate to get in to the UK.  Despair is not characteristic of a genuine visitor so if they begin to think that way, then matters will be worse.

Comment: Tangent: If OP deposited his cash pay into an account regularly and over a longer period of time than 3 months, would that make a letter from an employer more believable/creditable?

Comment: @mkennedy, not really.  It means he has a steady source of cash and nothing more.